# run the code in all subfolders

Tags: vb.net, directory, subdirectory

I got this code from somewhere in the net, and it works fine for me. However my experience is not enough to run it in all subfolders of the main one ("C:\Folder\").  I would appreciate any suggestion.

```
Sub check()
Dim strFolder As String
Dim strFile As String

  strFolder = "C:\Folder\"
  strFile = Dir(strFolder & "*.*")
  Do While Len(strFile) > 0
    If InStr(strFile, "xxx") > 0 Then
      Name strFolder & strFile As strFolder & Replace(strFile, "xxx", "yyy")
    End If
    strFile = Dir()
  Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: "I got this code from somewhere in the net," - what if it is malicious?

Comment: What on earth does this line do: `Name strFolder & strFile As strFolder & Replace(strFile, "xxx", "yyy")`? That does not look like valid VB.NET syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You're much better off using the System.IO namespace(you'll need to add the Imports statement for it), as there is a Directories.GetFiles method that allows for an option to search AllDirectories within your specified folder

Imports System.IO;

```
Sub Check()
 Dim strFolder As String = "C:\Folder\"
 Dim strFiles() As String = Directory.GetFiles(strFolder, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)

    For Each strFile As String In strFiles
        If strFile.Contains("xxx") Then
            File.Move(strFolder & strFile, strFolder & strFile.Replace("xxx", "yyy"))
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```